# Android: Subclass linearLayout do not set vertically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-linearlayout

I want to translate my code xml below, but in code that does not give me the same result, see the picture, left is the result in code, and right is the result in xml:

[image: Result]

Here is my subclass:

```
class FloatingButtonMultiple : LinearLayout {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    setup()
}

constructor(context: Context, @Nullable attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    setup()
}

constructor(context: Context, @Nullable attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    setup()
}


// MARK: - Set view

fun setup() {
    setLinearLayout()
    floatingBtn()
    addBtn()
}

private fun setLinearLayout() {
    val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
        addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)
    }

    orientation = VERTICAL

    this.layoutParams = params
}

private fun addBtn() {
    val linearParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT).apply {
        gravity = Gravity.END
        orientation = HORIZONTAL
    }

    val linearLayout = LinearLayout(context).apply {
        layoutParams = linearParams
    }

    // CardView
    val cardParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
        topMargin = 8.toDp
        marginEnd = 10.toDp
    }

    val cardView = CardView(context).apply {
        setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C4000000"))
        layoutParams = cardParams
    }

    //TextView
    val txtParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
        marginStart = 8.toDp
        marginEnd = 8.toDp
    }

    val txt = TextView(context).apply {
        text = "AAAAA"
        setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        layoutParams = txtParams
    }

    cardView.addView(txt)

    linearLayout.addView(cardView)

    //Btn
    val btnParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
        bottomMargin = 8.toDp
        marginEnd = 29.toDp
    }

    val btn = FloatingActionButton(context).apply {
        size = FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI
        layoutParams = btnParams
    }

    linearLayout.addView(btn)

    this.addView(linearLayout)
}

private fun floatingBtn() {
    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
        gravity = Gravity.END
        marginEnd = 20.toDp
        bottomMargin = 20.toDp
    }

    val btn = FloatingActionButton(context).apply {
        layoutParams = params
    }

    this.addView(btn)
}
```

Here my xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#C4000000">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="AAAA"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:fabSize="mini" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I do not understand I think I translated exactly the code xml code? Where is the problem? Why my subclass does not go vertical when I set it in the function `setLinearLayout()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

It's weird but changing the position of the functions, by calling `setLinearLayout()` last it works

Code:

```
fun setup() {
    floatingBtn()
    addBtn()
    setLinearLayout()
}
```

Comment: Putting it last might solve the problem, but you most certainly did not fix the true issue. I suspect some local val did over-write a `this` property..

Comment: Possible that there is a conflict between the two and that he is confused

Answer (score 0):

You need to set orientation to vertical on the following var in your code -

```
val linearLayout = LinearLayout(context).apply {
    layoutParams = linearParams
}
linearlayout.orientation = VERTICAL
```

Comment: No it's not this linear layout that I want in vertical, it's the subclass